# Variable nonSmoking is always null. How to set it to 1 or 0?

Tags: java

**When the code is 20, nonSmoking should be 1, but always returns null. After debugging I saw that it always returns null**

*How to set a variable nonSmoking correctly?*

```
public static String mapSmokingAmenities(ContentFragmentList list){
        SolrContentFragment solrFragments = list.getFragment(SolrContentFragment.class);
        List<String> ausstattungPositions = solrFragments.getAusstattungPosition();
        String nonSmoking = new String();
        for(String code : ausstattungPositions){
            if(code == "20" || code == "36"){
                nonSmoking = "1";
            }
            if(code == "51"){
                nonSmoking ="0";
            }
        }
        return nonSmoking;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It didn't help me

Comment: Have you verified that your DTO `solarFragments` is build correctly and got a list including data?
Sidenote: if it is not related to a special business naming which is always german for you please convert all code to english. Only business objects should be names in your common language, rest in english

Comment: The ContentFragmen is correct and returns a list of codes

Comment: my project requires these names

Comment: Me stupid. Strings are ofcause objects. using `==` you are comparing their address in memory. You need to use the `.equals()` method for a comparison of their value. So replace `==` by `"20".equals(code)`.
Note? "20" will every tiome newly created. It would make sense to source it out as enum or constant.

Comment: @AnidaMujezin "_It didn't help me_" ... did you check out the linked question (and its answers)? Because then you would find that comparing `String`s with `==` is not the way to go.

Comment: i changed == with equals and again my nonSmoking displays as null. see new picture above.

Comment: Your picture appears to show the debugger *just before* it assigns a value of "1". (It's also worth noting that null and a reference to an empty string are different things.)

Comment: `nonSmoking` is an empty String (as @JonSkeet says, just before it is assigned to). That method will never return null.

Comment: this is the image after the last changes, now it shows me an empty String (nonSmoking)

Comment: @LenglBoy: "Note? "20" will every tiome newly created. It would make sense to source it out as enum or constant." - no, that's not true. String literals already *are* constants. They don't involve creating a new instance every time execution goes through code using them.

Comment: Your code would *never* have returned a null reference. And again, you're showing the value as an empty string *before you assign a new value to it*. If you still believe there's a problem, please provide a [mcve], ideally as a console app, so that we can run it and reproduce the problem. That would be much, much more useful than debugger screenshots (especially when the code in the debugger no longer matches the text in the post.)

Comment: @user16320675 I changed it just to see the latest changes, i went back to the original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing objects using `==` compares the address. You can find out if a object points to the same instance you want to work with. Only primitive datatypes (int/...) can be compared with value like that.
For Strings as being object please use `equals()` method for the value compare.

If you have custom DTO/POJO where you want to compare value and not reference you need to overwrite the `hashCode` and `equals` method there.

Comment: Address is misleading. It compares , if the compared instances are the same.

Comment: The switch-case solution from @MichaelKatt will work as well. Just apply what fits your codestyle best - for us it was we never use jumps and switch-case.

Comment: Ups forgot magic word _by reference_

Answer (score 2):

Probably this could help

```
public static String mapSmokingAmenities(ContentFragmentList list){
    SolrContentFragment solrFragments = list.getFragment(SolrContentFragment.class);
    List<String> ausstattungPositions = solrFragments.getAusstattungPosition();
    String nonSmoking = "";
    for(String code : ausstattungPositions){
        switch(code) {
            case "20":
            case "36":
               nonSmoking = "1";
               break;
           case "51":
               nonSmoking = "0";
               break;
           default:
               // do nothing
               break;
        }
    }
    return nonSmoking;
}
```

You should use an enum for your codes and your result. Be aware, that you set `nonSmoking` every time being code 20, 36 or 51. Probably you should break your `for` loop. Don't create a new String but use an empty String `""`.